# When I go to Sugar CRM studio page it shows "An error has occurred"?

Tags: sugarcrm

When I go to Admin -> Studio -> it shows the error:

```
{"center":{"title":"Studio","crumb":"\"\"<\/a> | Studio<\/a> "
```

Can you please suggest me where I did a mistake. I have backup also but I can't move all the files. Because I have done so many changes in this. if I moved all the files I will lose those changes.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP/HTML file is not properly terminated causing that error. 
Have you modified the php files?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response...After development it's in UAT testing. I haven't done anything from my side. I am getting tickets from testing team. so that I tried to open again this project. can you please help me.. where changes need to be done?

Comment: I am not able to share my screenshot becoz of less reputation.

Comment: If you have not done anything with the script/files, changes are that the  development have sent you a half working copy of your CMS/CRM.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help finding the issue if I can't get a copy of the files. 

Who installed the script/program? Where was it installed?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If yes then how?